# StreamWriter is changing some Japanese chars to some strange chars in C#

Tags: encoding, utf-8, base64, streamwriter, cjk

I have an input string `displayName` which is in `base64` format, used for comparison.

```
displayName:: Rmlyc3ROYW1lW0FCQ0Q65LqL5qWt5qeL6YCg5pS56Z2p6YOoIOizvOiyt+alreWLmeS8geeUu+OD
```

geODvOODoF0oRmlyc3ROYW1lKQ==

We are converting `base64` value to a `byte[]` then to a string using `Encoding.UTF8`

```
byte[] newbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(displayname);
string displaynameReadable = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newbytes);
```

Output `displaynameReadable = FirstName[ABCD:事業構造改革部 購買業務企画チーム](FirstName)`

So while writing the values in a .csv file. I am using StringWriter.

```
StringWriter writer;
writer = new StreamWriter(writeFIle);
```

It has to write the value of `displaynameReadable` in the csv file which includes the Japanese chars.
But after using `streamWriter`, its converting the Japanese chars of `displaynameReadable` to some strange chars

Output after stream writer:

```
displayName = FIRSTNAME[ABCD:äº‹æ¥­æ§‹é€ æ”¹é©éƒ¨ è³¼è²·æ¥­å‹™ä¼ç”»ãƒãƒ¼ãƒ ](FIRSTNAME)
```

I guess the default Encoding used in streamWriter is Encoding.UTF8
Not able to get the `Japanese` chars in the ouput file

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have written the output with `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`. see [the result of CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27,true)Decode_text(%27Windows-1252%20Latin%20(1252)%27)&input=Um1seWMzUk9ZVzFsVzBGQ1EwUTY1THFMNXFXdDVxZUw2WUNnNXBTNTZaMnA2WU9vSU9penZPaXl0K2FscmVXTG1lUzhnZWVVdStPRGdlT0R2T09Eb0Ywb1JtbHljM1JPWVcxbEtRPT0).

If you want to make a `.csv` file readable with Excel, you have to write the `.csv` with `Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")` (UTF8 with BOM), or `Encoding.GetEncoding(932)` (MS932).

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string displayname = "Rmlyc3ROYW1lW0FCQ0Q65LqL5qWt5qeL6YCg5pS56Z2p6YOoIOizvOiyt+alreWLmeS8geeUu+ODgeODvOODoF0oRmlyc3ROYW1lKQ==";
        byte[] newbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(displayname);
        string displaynameReadable = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newbytes);
        // Console.WriteLine(displaynameReadable);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("/path/to/csv", false, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
        sw.WriteLine(displaynameReadable);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```